# ¿Cómo guardar un .txt en una ruta especifica usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, rutas

Estoy usando este código:

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{      
// grab the content of the form field and place it into a variable
    var textToWrite = "Esto podría ser una larga historia, pero de momento, tan solo es una prueba"
//  create a new Blob (html5 magic) that conatins the data from your form feild
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
// Specify the name of the file to be saved
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "myNewFile.txt";

// Optionally allow the user to choose a file name by providing 
// an imput field in the HTML and using the collected data here
// var fileNameToSaveAs = txtFileName.text;

// create a link for our script to 'click'
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
//  supply the name of the file (from the var above).
// you could create the name here but using a var
// allows more flexability later.
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
// provide text for the link. This will be hidden so you
// can actually use anything you want.
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";

// allow our code to work in webkit & Gecko based browsers
// without the need for a if / else block.
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// Create the link Object.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
// when link is clicked call a function to remove it from
// the DOM in case user wants to save a second file.
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
// make sure the link is hidden.
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
// add the link to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

// click the new link
    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
// remove the link from the DOM
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

// EOF
```

Lo que estoy buscando es poder guardar un archivo en una ruta que yo le dé, porque este código siempre te guarda los archivos en la carpeta de downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible. Por motivos de seguridad los navegadores no permiten que un sitio pueda guardar archivos en cualquier ruta en el dispositivo del usuario.

Comment: A no ser que el código se esté ejecutando sobre nodejs en servidor o aplicación de escritorio, pero no, no parece el caso.

Comment: @javrd: ¿Pero si el navegador le pide permiso al usuario? ¿Y le pide que especifique la ruta?

Comment: @javrd: ¿Y cómo lo hacen en páginas cómo esta https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif  para subir archivos?

Comment: Esa es una pregunta completamente distinta, pero es fácil, es el tipo del input del formulario, `file`.